# Google App Engine for an application in a local network

Tags: google-app-engine, lamp

I have this application that will be run in a local network where a number of devices should interact with a database. I could use xampp and go for CherryPy or any other Python framework (Python is usually my choice) but it is the sum of a lot of different things: Python, Apache, MySQL... With GAE, which I have previously used in a number of applications successfully, I feel everything is neatly packed in a single box. Thay may not be true, but using the Google App Engine Launcher to create a local working copy of an app couldn't be easier.

But is it reliable? Should it be used like that? I know it's intended for development, so I'm unsure about using it as a local server in production. A few versions ago there even was this nasty bug that flushed the local datastore from time to time. But it seems that they fixed it and now data persists.

Would you recommend GAE for an application running in a local network or should I stick to LAMP (P for Python)?

Comment: Well, no need for CherryPy, really. I would do just a local Python webserver, which I've used before too. So it would be a matter of installing MySQL and other required pieces of software vs just GAE.

Comment: I think I'm replying myself, but the more I look for info the clearer it gets. I should use Bottle of Flask with SQLite, probably. I don't need much more than that.

Answer (score 2):

Other alternative is http://code.google.com/p/appscale/.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can check the the project [TyphoonAE](http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/). I think it is exactly what you need.

> The TyphoonAE project aims at providing a full-featured and productive
>   serving environment to run Google App Engine (Python) applications. It
>   delivers the parts for building your own scalable App Engine while
>   staying compatible with Google's API.